# DISK IO Hit 100% in Mysql 8

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am using MySQL 8 on Centos 7 and Centos 8 and I am running a simple count statement on 27GB table. Usually, it takes around 10 secs in MySQL 5.7 but here in MySQL 8, it's taking around 10 mins. I found whenever run this command then my disk IO chucked to 100%. Is there any luck

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test.logs_sync`

Answer (score 0):

Infact issue fixed under below work around and now taking only 5-sec

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test.logs_sync where id>0;
```